# Inserting multiplication sign in superscript in-text

Tags: math-mode, symbols, superscripts

On overleaf, I am trying to write out matrix `X` in all real numbers `^ (P x P)`, where `x` is a multiplication sign, in the middle of a paragraph of text.

So far, I have

```
$X$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{P\timesP}$.
```

For some reason, I am not able to get the superscript of `R` (all real numbers) to have `(P x P)`. I can only get a single `P`. Could someone provide help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: please, can you explain better your problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why going in and out of math mode? The standard `$X\in \mathbb{R}^{P\times P}$` will work. Note the space after `\times`.

Comment: Don't ignore error messages! you have `\timesP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
 $X$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{P\timesP}$.
\end{document}
```

Produces the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4  $X$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{P\timesP
                                    }$.
?
```

Don't ignore error messages, after any error, the PDF is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid.  Here you simply need a space to separate the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
 $X$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{P\times P}$.
\end{document}
```

Although I would write it as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
 $X \in \mathbb{R}^{P\times P}$.
\end{document}
```

to get math spacing rather than sentence spacing around `\in`.